# How to pass list of string as function argument in python?

Tags: python, string, list, function, parameters

I'm having a list of string and i need to pass it to function as a parameter.

```
a_list = ['apple-banana','brinjal-carrot','cucumber']

function_call = fruit(a_list)

def fruit(a_list):
  print("Inside Function:")
  print(a_list)
  if(len(a_list)!=0):
     for i in a_list:
        print(i)
```

But what I'm getting for a_list is something like this:

```
['a','p','p','l','e','-','b','a','n','a','n','a',....]
```

What I need is:

```
Inside Function:
'apple-banana'
'brinjal-carrot'
'cucumber'
```

Where I'm going wrong.?

Thanks.

Comment: running your code gives the expected output. You should call `fruit` after the declaration though

Comment: I don't see any problem in your code except that your sample is using `fruit` before actually making it ;)

Comment: move the call to `fruit function` after the `fruit func definition` n try

Comment: There seems no problem in your code... it works completely fine

Comment: Unrelated, but `if(len(a_list)!=0):` can be shortened to `if a_list:` and is redundant anyway (if the list is empty, the loop will not execute, and if it is not iterable, the `len` part will fail, too).

Answer (score 0):

Removing the redundant code with some highlights:

```
a_list = ['apple-banana','brinjal-carrot','cucumber']

def fruit(a_list):       # no need to check for the len or if the a_list exists, the for loop takes care of that
    for i in a_list:           
        print(i)
        
fruit(a_list) # your function is not returning anything so no point of assigning
```

OUTPUT:

```
apple-banana                                                                                                                                                                
brinjal-carrot                                                                                                                                                              
cucumber
```